# Running power through a faceplate to code?

Tags: wiring, hvac, code-compliance

I have a new HVAC system in a closet where the blower plugs into a socket, which is how the old one was setup. Inspector says the plug is no good, it has to be wired in.
So, it's a 2 gang plastic box, Plastic faceplate, and currently has a switch alongside duplex sockets which the switch controls (110 v, 20amp circuit). Power cord is plastic insulated 16/2 w/ ground. Location is Texas (owner, homestead).

My first thought is to just cut off the plug, cut a notch in the faceplate, feed the cable in and wire it to the switch while separating the switch and sockets, and then just secure the cable to the wall.

Option 2 is replace the duplex sockets with a switch/socket combo and cut the faceplate's switch slot bigger to accommodate a standard 3/8 connector. But can a metal connector be used on a plastic faceplate? Does modifying a faceplate automatically break code? Do they make a 2g duplex/punch-out faceplate?

Option 3. (Don't really want to go this far) Rip out the plastic box and replace it with a metal box and metal faceplate using option 2's configuration.

3b. Also replace the plug and cable with conduit, using a 90 degree connector at the box.

Will any of these options likely work, or is there a best way to do this I'm missing?

Note: I'll likely go down to city hall and talk to someone to make sure the plan meets code (may even need a separate permit). I'd just like to have a solid plan first.

Comment: Conduit plus duplex outlet covers are readily available. Use flex conduit to the blower.

Comment: Please post a picture of the plug end, and the specs for the unit

Comment: What code is the inspector citing to say that the blower cannot be cord & plug connected?